# Get a gpx file from the boundaries of a city

Tags: google-maps, gpx

Is it possible to get a gpx file from the boundaries of a city displayed in Google Maps.
For example, this boundary: [City Boundaries](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Manitou+Springs,+CO/@38.8500092,-104.9361781,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8713509fcf049499:0xa53d21dbae6b97ab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the boundaries of a city in KML from google maps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78376/how-to-get-the-boundaries-of-a-city-in-kml-from-google-maps)

Comment: It is similar. That question is 2 years old, could functionality have changed?

Comment: try openstreetmap for exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be using the [U.S. Census Bureaus Boundary Annexation Survey](http://www.census.gov/geo/partnerships/bas.html) (BAS) data, for the areas you need municipal boundaries for, and convert it to a format that suits your needs. This ensures that your boundaries are as up to date as possible.